# Opposite of FORMAT function in Excel

Tags: excel

I have bunch of phone number is an Excel sheet.  The user was inconsistent in their inputs.

```
(512) 555-1212
713.261.8976
2038948870
(202) 432-9876X12
```

in order to import them into out corporate Database I need to get all of the "extra" stuff stripped
I would like the first 10 INEGERs  so my result would be:

```
5125551212
7132618976
2038948870
2024329876
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Hi Tim.  Thanks for looking at it for me.    The other folks have graphically illustrated the problem.    Hope this clears it up for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute can do what you're asking for

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",""),")",""),"-",""), " ",""),".",""),10)
```

[image]